# Regular Expression with Minecraft Console and nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, minecraft

I am making a wrapper for the minecraft server, and I have been stuck on this one Regex match problem for Ages. Basically I want to match the following segment

```
[04:57:40] [Server thread/INFO]: <§c§lAdmin §7§oUser1§r> msg
[04:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: <§c§lAdmin §7§oUser2§r> msg
[04:58:16] [Server thread/INFO]: <§c§lAdmin §7§oUser1§r> msg
[04:58:28] [Server thread/INFO]: <§4§lCoOwner §7§oUser2§r> msg
[04:58:33] [Server thread/INFO]: <§c§lAdmin §7§oUser1§r> msg
                                  ^-------------------^<--That
```

Now, for those unfamiliar with minecraft username stuff, there are three parts:

- **Prefix:** Consists of 0-16 characters, including '§'. '§' Must be followed by a letter or number.
- **Username:** Letters, numbers, and underscore, anywhere in between 3 and 16 characters long. `[\w\d]{3,16}` Easily satisfies this.
- **Suffix:** Same as prefix

So out of the above, I need those 3 sections seperated.

Is there a way to do this in JS RegExp? The only way I can think of is using lookbehinds. Would it be better to make a JS function to parse this? If so, how would I go about doing it?

**EDIT 1:** This Is my current regex `(?:[§&\d\w ]){0,16}?(\w{3,16})(?:[§&\d\w ]){0,16}`, given the following line of input:

```
<§4&btest &r&rKaidenP§r> woo
```

Pattern group #1 is `rKaidenP`. It needs to be just KaidenP

Comment: Just a clarification when you say `rKaidenP` should be `KaidenP` does that mean in the username portion the first characters after the `§` should be ignored? As the username in the test input appears to be `rKaidenP`

Comment: So a single charge is ignored after that symbol.

Comment: Note that the section-signs shouldn't be put into the log; that's a bug (but not one that's likely to get fixed any time soon).  See [MC-112693](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-112693), and vote for it if you want it fixed.  There's also a craftbukkit PR that fixes it there (in a fancier way, which also fixes a few vanilla functions that were broken regarding chat hovering), which I wrote but don't have the link for right now (if you're interested, I'll get it later).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand corectly next char fafter § and & should be ignored:

So i would do this:

```js
const getMessageInfo = line => {
  line = line.replace(/[\&§]./g, '')
  const info = line.match(/<(\S+)\s*(\S+?)?>\s(.*)/)
  return {
    role: info[2] ? info[1] : 'User',
    username: info[2] || info[1],
    message: info[3]
  }
}

const data = [
'[04:57:40] [Server thread/INFO]: <Admin User1> msg',
'[04:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: <Admin User2> msg',
'[04:58:16] [Server thread/INFO]: <Admin User1> msg',
'[04:58:28] [Server thread/INFO]: <CoOwner User2> msg',
'[04:58:33] [Server thread/INFO]: <Admin User1> msg',
'[04:58:33] [Server thread/INFO]: <User1> msg',
'<§4&btest &r&rKaidenP§r> woo'
]

for (const line of data) {
  const msg = getMessageInfo(line)
  console.log(line)
  console.log(msg)
}
```

Comment: OK,  I honestly don't know why I didn't think of splitting it up like that. I didn't want the next char ignored but ignoring it is no loss so this works. Thanks

Comment: But I just realized, if therequired is no prefix, the rege won't match. So for instance <KaidenP>

Comment: why should it ?

Comment: @KaidenPrince try now it didn't work because you did not specified this in examples

Comment: I'm just going to make some sort of parser